# In .NET Core library, how can I determine the current environment is UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core

I'm writing a library for .NET Core and found that I have to use StreamSocket instead of Socket and SslStream when this library is used within UWP app. How can/should my code determine if the current environment is UWP so that my code will switch to StreamSocket codepath in this case?

Comment: Something like this?: `Environment.OSVersion`

Comment: I guess i's just OS. I can run UWP app on Windows 10, for instance. It does not state if SslStream will be available or not (it can be available in another kind of app, like under .NET 4.5.2 or in ASP.NET Core on the same platform).

Comment: It is rather interesting that you should be able to use Socket and SslStream, by using the related .NET Core packages on UWP.

Comment: @LexLi Not sure I understood your comment. Are you suggesting something?

Comment: @Alex threads like https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3189

Comment: @LexLi These threads show how to reference .NET Core lib from UWP app. I have no problems with that, I'm already using my .NET Core lib from there. I just can't detect in runtime that the lib is currently being run within a UWP app. Seems I'll have to create separate version of my library specially targeted to UWP if I want to use UWP-specific functionality (like StreamSocket instead of SslStream which is not available there)..

Comment: @Alex if you can use .NET Core packages, then why cannot you use the packages that give you `Socket` type and other missing types?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130594/discussion-between-alex-and-lex-li).